# Texture sampling precision problem in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, precision

I'm having a problem sampling textures in OpenGL ES on Android. The object I'm sampling is a terrain tile, and the texture coordinates are generated based on the x-z position of each vertex. For a typical tile, the texture coordinates will range between -5 and 5 (meaning my texture should be repeated 10 times over the terrain tile).

When I look at the shader running on Android, it looks totally fine towards the centre of a tile, but towards the edges, where texture coordinates are larger, I get what I assume are precision problems in the sampling:

[image: Terrain texture precision problem]

Is this normal? If so, what should I limit my texture coordinates to in order to prevent it? 0 to 1? I'm just sending the raw texture coordinates (-5 to 5) straight into the shader right now as a float2. The texture is 512x512.

Note also that I'm not setting precision manually in the shaders; they are automatically generated from HLSL code. I'm using MonoGame to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Clamping it in [0; 1] range might be problematic, easier for procedural content would be to aim for [0;2) range.

In any case, it shouldn't be about some exact range of values for texture coordinates, [-5;5] should work ok too. What's important is the size relations, how distant are texture's 0 and 1 coordinates in screen space. If you stretch the texture to cover few virtual 'kilometers' on screen, then indeed there will be difficulties with precision. Single onscreen polygon will have very short span within texture space, requiring more bits to interpolate texture coordinates.

Start with decreasing the texture stretching over the world.

Comment: For floats always try to clamp to `[-1,1)` because you exploit the sign-bit to maintain more precision than `[0,2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Just to let you know, I already tried the typical trick of just taking the fractional part of the TexCoords, but I ran into the (also typical) problem of seams caused by mipmapping. Would clamping [-1, 1) avoid this problem?

Comment: @user3621637 what's the current scale of the texture image relative to the screen area?

Comment: At the moment, a 512x512 texture is covering an area of 100m. The screen area is 1024x600.

Comment: @user3621637 not in pixels, what's the size relation? Your texture covers 100m, how many meters there across the screen width in the camera's vicinity? Not the viewing depth, but the width of the screen in 'meters' at the camera clipping plane.

Comment: 100m/512 = ~20 centimeters per texel. Assuming a typical first-person visual field,  I suspect the problem is that your textures are just not high enough resolution. Odd that you are getting lines in one direction and blurs in the other though. Can you share a reproducer?